# Compilation Error - are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Tags: c#, asp.net, compiler-errors

After i debug the program, 
the page show me the following error.
I have no idea to solve this error, **is that missing the assemblies**?

Here is the error their show:

**Compilation Error**

> **Description**: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following
>   specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> **Compiler Error Message**: CS1061: 'ASP.dcbrequestlogcriteria_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'ddlTelco_SelectedIndexChanged' and
>   no extension method 'ddlTelco_SelectedIndexChanged' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'ASP.dcbrequestlogcriteria_aspx' could be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Source Error:

```
<span class="fieldlable">Telco:</span>
<span>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTelco" runat="server" DataTextField="Text" DataValueField="Value"  AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlTelco_SelectedIndexChanged" SelectMethod="LoadTelco"  Enabled="false"></asp:DropDownList>
</span>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidatorTelco" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Telco" ControlToValidate="ddlTelco"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Comment: The error message tells exactly what the problem is...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that it is looking for the event **ddlTelco_SelectedIndexChanged** which you have subscribed to your control

On the code behind of your markup, define an event for **ddlTelco_SelectedIndexChanged** or by subscribing your control to an event and generate

**ddlTelco.OnSelectedIndexChanged += ddlTelco_SelectedIndexChanged**

```
    protected void ddlTelco_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    //Write implementation here
    }
```

and rebuild.

Answer (score 1):

You have assigned the event handler `ddlTelco_SelectedIndexChanged` to the   `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event of the `DropDownList` But you forgot to define it in the back-end, or it may be deleted.

If you really want to do something with `OnSelectedIndexChanged` define `ddlTelco_SelectedIndexChanged` in the back end and **rebuild the solution**. If you don't want means remove `OnSelectedIndexChanged` from the markup